# remove root tag from xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2, root

I have an xml file like this

```
<root>
<level1>data</level1>
<level1>data</level1>
.
.
.
<level1>data</level1>
<level1>data</level1>
</root>
```

I want to remove the root tag using xslt. can anyone help me?
my problem is that I have multi level 1 data.

thanks for any help

Comment: If you remove the root element, you will end up with something that looks like an XML document, but isn't. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: yes, I am sure. for some processing I should do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're sure that's what you want to do, you could do it simply by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, I cannot stress this strongly enough: the result in your example will be an [XML fragment](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-fragment.html#d1e275), not a [well-formed XML document](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed).

Comment: it gives me this error " Illegal to have multiple roots" what should I do?

Comment: What exactly is "it"? Which processor are you using?

Comment: I am using wso2 esb, and changing an output from one proxy

Comment: That's not an XSLT processor. I am guessing the error is coming not from the XSL transformation itself, but from the following step in your processing chain - which is exactly what I warned you about.

Comment: however it gives me error, but it helps me in other code. thanks a lot